# nested object under path ['somepath'] is not of nested type

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, elasticsearch-5

I am getting the following error when I try to query the data

**Error**

[nested] nested object under path [existing_contacts] is not of nested type

**Data in index**

```
{
        "_index" : "memoreasecontacts",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "614d6f0b2a05640008d09109",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "614d6f0b2a05640008d09109",
          "existing_contacts" : [
            {
              "is_profile_completed" : true,
              "friend_status" : "pending",
              "email_verified" : false,
              "gender" : "Male",
              "is_new_signup" : "true",
              "religious_id" : [
                {
                  "religious" : "Hinduism",
                  "id" : "5db7d2a36a57364618c57efe"
                }
              ],
              "email_token" : "VZs37yfesXbCsRuWGJPqgZxVn1Xz55Qh",
              "profileImage" : "uploads/userimage.png",
              "deviceId" : [ ],
              "friend_owner" : "receiver",
              "blocked_status" : false,
              "lastname" : "Shahbaz",
              "password" : "$F0EaWeYX=d5#Q3Jld2xvZ2l4QDE=",
              "mobile_verified" : true,
              "created_on" : "2021-09-24T12:49:24.674Z",
              "dob" : "2021-09-24T00:00:00.000Z",
              "selfinformation" : "Testing app",
              "firtsname" : "Umer",
              "id" : "614dc95412b8c0000903cd5c",
              "email" : "m.haris+10@crewlogix.com",
              "username" : "UmerShahbaz"
            }
          ],
          "new_contacts" : [ ]
        }
      }
```

**Query**

```
"query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_id": {
              "value": "614d6f0b2a05640008d09109"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "ignore_unmapped": true,
            "path": "existing_contacts",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "existing_contacts.friend_status": "pending"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "existing_contacts.friend_owner": "receiver"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            "inner_hits": {
              "size": "1",
              "from": "0",
              "highlight": {
                "fields": {
                  "existing_contacts.username": {},
                  "existing_contacts.friend_status": {}
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

**P.S**

This was working before. AWS elastic search domain went down and I have to replace it with the new domain. Now getting this error. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**Mapping**

```
{
  "memoreasecontacts" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "existing_contacts" : {
          "properties" : {
            "blocked_status" : {
              "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "created_on" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "dob" : {
              "type" : "date"
            },
            "email" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "email_token" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "email_verified" : {
              "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "firtsname" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "friend_owner" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "friend_status" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "gender" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "id" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "is_new_signup" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "is_profile_completed" : {
              "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "lastname" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "mobile" : {
              "type" : "long"
            },
            "mobile_verified" : {
              "type" : "boolean"
            },
            "password" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "profileImage" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "religious_id" : {
              "properties" : {
                "id" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                },
                "religious" : {
                  "type" : "text",
                  "fields" : {
                    "keyword" : {
                      "type" : "keyword",
                      "ignore_above" : 256
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "selfinformation" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            },
            "username" : {
              "type" : "text",
              "fields" : {
                "keyword" : {
                  "type" : "keyword",
                  "ignore_above" : 256
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "id" : {
          "type" : "text",
          "fields" : {
            "keyword" : {
              "type" : "keyword",
              "ignore_above" : 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1632463671805",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "ckUxjK5wQoOiagEINEwb0w",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "7040299"
        },
        "provided_name" : "memoreasecontacts"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the object really of type nested? You can use ```GET index-name/``` to get the index mapping. Threw that you can check the object type.

Comment: yes the mapping is correct, Let me add the mapping to the question as well.

Comment: When I delete all the data and insert a new record it starts working, after adding some records it gives the above error. That's very strange behavior.

Comment: "existing_contacts" is not being defined type nested.
[elasticsearch nested field type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)

Comment: Ok, can you please help me understand what changes should I make to make it nested? because I did not define the type with the rest of the fields. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Sure. You need to create a mapping for your index. That mapping can be applied on index creation or threw an index template.
[index template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-templates.html)
You can also do it manually using kibana. By going to menu Stack management->Index management->index template

Comment: Thanks @MacJ I have fixed the issue by define the mapping for existing_contacts type as nested. Now its working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a mapping for your index. That mapping can be applied on index creation or threw an index template. index template You can also do it manually using kibana. By going to menu Stack management->Index management->index template